# Shift + t key not working - Possibly registered as a shortcut

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever I try to type an uppercase t (T) using shift nothing happens and I have to resort to using Caps lock which is annoying.

This is true for both the left and right shift keys. I do not think this is a hardware problem since the issue persists when using the onscreen keyboard, and hence suspect that the key combination might be under use as a shortcut in some app.

Comment: What OS? Does the same happen on a different keyboard? Is it the same in all apps? Does it work before login? Have you tried a different user account, or safe mode? Do you have any command-mod software installed? You really have given us very little to work with here.